# Powershell Print Word Document

Tags: powershell

I have a .txt document and a MS Word .doc that I would like send to the printer. Running the Powershell `Start-Process -FilePath C:\Temp\Versions.TXT -Verb print` works fine for the .txt file.

But when I use the Powershell command `Start-Process -FilePath C:\Temp\Versions.docx -Verb print`, I get the error below.

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'version'.
At line:1 char:14
+ Start-Process <<<<  -FilePath C:\Temp\Versions.docx -Verb print
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

What is going wrong? Could someone please provide some assistance?

Comment: I just tried it and it worked fine for me--printed the Word document.  Are you sure you don't inadvertently have a space in your path?  You may want to enclose it in quotes just in case.

Comment: Sorry my original post wasn't correct as the file name does contain the spaces. It seems the error appears when the file name contains the spaces. This command powershell Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\MB New version federal CS_26207.doc" -Verb print doesn't work. But this command works, powershell Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\MB_New_version_federal_CS_26207.doc" -Verb print. I need to use the spaces in the file name, is there any way to get around this? Thanks

Comment: I tried it with the same directory structure and Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\MB New version federal CS_26207.doc" -Verb print works. What is the exception ?

Comment: Here it is:

Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'v
ersion'.
At line:1 char:14
+ Start-Process <<<<  -FilePath C:\Temp\MB New version federal CS_26207.doc -Ve
rb print
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterB 
   indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell 
   .Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: It worked when I used the single quote instead of double quote. Thank you Nate for leading me to the right direction.

powershell Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Temp\MB New version federal CS_26207.doc' -Verb print

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not `-Verb Print`

Take a second and read the error message:

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'version'.
```

It sais, that no parameter was found which accepts `version`

You have only one word "Version" in your code line, `Versions.TXT`

Try please following:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\Versions.TXT" -Verb print
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I'll edit it when I saw the hole script
Because what he current post it, it would get this exception

Comment: When you see the whole script and you have an answer, that's the time to write an answer.

Comment: I did, and removed my comment (and upvoted your answer). You must have been editing while I was commenting. :-)

Comment: Please see my response above. Thanks

Comment: I did put the put the file name between the quotes but it didn't help. I found that if I removed the spaces in the file name then it works. Thanks

Comment: when I remove the quotes, then I'll recieve exactly the same exception as you.
Are you really sure, that you have it inside the quotes ? I don't think so @Doug

Comment: That's strange. This doesn't work powershell Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\MB New version federal CS_26207.doc" -Verb print. But this works 
powershell Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\MB_New_version_federal_CS_26207.doc" -Verb print. As you can see, I just removed the spaces in the file name and it works. Is there a reason? Thanks

Comment: Are you also sure, that the document name really contain these spaces ? @Doug

Comment: Not sure what you meant by that. Here is the file name MB New version federal CS_26207.doc. Please let me know if you any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have any more answer for this special issue @Doug

Comment: It worked when I used the single quote instead of double quote. Thank you Solaflex for leading me to the right direction.

powershell Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Temp\MB New version federal CS_26207.doc' -Verb print

Thank you

Comment: @Doug, please fix your original question to include the actual file name, and then answer your own question.  You'll be able to mark your own solution as the accepted answer in 24 hours.